# View has become null in onResume() - But only in app downloaded from Play Store

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

This is a weird one,

When resuming an app from the `launch` icon in Android, I'm getting a crash on the version of my app on the Play Store.

This only occurs on some devices and ONLY on the version of the app on the Play Store - It doesn't even occur on the original APK uploaded to the Play Store.

The logging clearly shows the error is a `NullPointerException` occuring in `onResume()` when I'm trying to access a `TextView` created in `onCreate()`

My issue is, since I have no way of debugging the application (without uploading a new version of the App to the App store), I can't figure out if this is some sort of lifecycle error, or if the variable is being recycled when the `Activity` is destroyed.

**Why is a `View` variable assigned during `onCreate()` becoming `null` in `onResume()`?**

**Edit**

Since code was asked for - The `Fragment` is pretty large, so I've removed all code that doesn't reference the `View`. The variable `mWifi` is not accessed, referenced or assigned anywhere else in the file.

```
private TextView mWifi;

@Override
protected View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) { {
    View toReturn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signin, null);

    mWifi = (TextView)toReturn.findViewById(R.id.wifi);

    return toReturn;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {    
    super.onResume();

    mWifi.setText(getWifiSSID(getActivity()));
}
```

Comment: Post some code, please.

Comment: Maybe it is being reset somewhere later.

Comment: Added code - code is complete as far as the null variable is concerned. It is not referenced anywhere else in the file.

Comment: Seems like Fragment's onResume() is called before onCreateView() by FragmentManager. I don't know if it's possible but normally shouldn't happen. I would just check for null as SacreDeveloper suggested in this case.

Comment: If `mWifi` isn't used anywhere else, I'd just eliminate it and use a call to `findViewByid` inside `onResume`. (Similar to what @DoctororDrive suggests.) It doesn't solve the mystery of why this is happening but should eliminate the behavior in the wild. Can you tell whether the problem is limited to a particular device or to certain device types (API levels, manufacturers, etc.)?

Comment: @TedHopp It *doesn't* occur on Nexus devices but it *does* occur on Samsung devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this was being caused by two broadcasts being fired back to back.

In that instance, two `Fragments` were loaded at the exact same time.

I'm wondering if perhaps for some reason the Fragments were interfering with each other, as the life-cycle states for instantiation etc. would be almost synchronised but ever so slightly "off".

As of now, since I've fixed the problem by ensuring the broadcast happens only once, I'm assuming this is an OS bug caused from an Edge case scenario.